# Use class of top section and footage section on every page of website from one common css file

Tags: php, html, css

I have top section and footage section common on all pages of my website. I have css classes defined for these sections. What I want to do is to create common file of classes of these two sections and use it on every page, so that if I want to edit something in this section, I have to do it at one place only.

I have different css for middle section of each web page. So if I want create one common css file for top and bottom section, I have to have two css files for one web page. So my real question is can I have two css files for one web page? If yes, how to include and manage them? If no, is there any way to achieve my purpose?

And the best solution will be if I don't need to change html of each page also. If I can create an html page which has top and bottom section. And use this html page on every web page. It will be very useful, as it will save many edits, if I want to change something.

Comment: You do know that your stylesheets  don't have to be loaded in the same order as the html they effect!!??

Comment: You can include multiple CSS files in same page. The syntax is same as to include 1 file, just repeat it multiple times with different filenames.

Comment: ok, I got that. I edited my question to meet my exact requirement(common html code in one file used on each page ), can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your using php (according to your tags) as your scripting language you can use php includes to create your header, main content and footer.

Page: MainContent.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerStyles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainStyles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="footerStyles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
     <?php include("header.php"); ?>
     <p>Main Content</p>
     <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your header.php and footer.php then contain your code for those respective pages.

Personally I wouldn't recommend separate style sheets as it will increase your page load time because the client needs to make separate calls to retrieve these files. I'm sure you have common styles and creating one stylesheet will be more efficient to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem to link two different style sheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commonStyles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="specificAboutUsPageStyle.css" />
```

Comment: ok, I got that. I edited my question to meet my exact requirement(common html code in one file used on each page ), can I achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple CSS files for a web page, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header_footer.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
```

Within the header_footer.css, define your styles, for header and footer.